# What to do about "transaction nonce too high" errors in RSK?

Tags: web3js, rsk

I have a decentralised application deployed on RSK, and has been working for several months. Everything works correctly using the public node,
however infrequently, we start getting a totally random error:

```json
Unknown Error: { 
  "jsonrpc": "2.0", 
  "id": 2978041344968143, 
  "error": { 
    "code": -32010, 
    "message": "transaction nonce too high" 
  } 
}
```

There is no information about “too high” nonces but many threads about “too slow”. I’m using `web3.Contract.method.send()`.

Answer (score 14):

In Metamask, ensure you are on your dev/test account then:

1 click on the avatar circle top right
2 In the menu, choose Settings
3 Click Advanced
4 Scroll down a bit, make sure again you are on your testnet account, click Reset Account

Answer (score 7):

There is a limit on the number transactions the same address can have on the transaction pool.

This limit is **4** for RSK,
and is defined within [`TxValidatorNonceRangeValidator`](https://github.com/rsksmart/rskj/blob/PAPYRUS-2.1.0/rskj-core/src/main/java/co/rsk/net/handler/txvalidator/TxValidatorNonceRangeValidator.java#L39)
within the **rskj** code base:

```java
BigInteger maxNumberOfTxsPerAddress = BigInteger.valueOf(4);
```

Note that Ethereum has a similar limit,
but the limit that is configured in **geth** is **10**.
So if we have already sent 4 transactions, that have not been mined yet, and send a 5th transaction before the next block is mined, it will get an error that the nonce is too high. If a block was mined and it had let's say all 4 of the transactions, then we would be able to add up to 4 transactions for the next block.

**Workarounds**

(1) Send no more than 4 transactions from an address, until there is a new block.

(2) Aggregate all of the calls and then use a contract that executes them in a single go.
An example of this is seen in
[RNS Batch Client `ExecuteRegistrations`](https://github.com/rnsdomains/rns-rskdomains-batch-client/blob/master/src/components/ExecuteRegistrations.js#L363).

Answer (score 1):

For me it happened when i restarted the node, following instruction fixed it:

> Open up your MetaMask window and click on the icon in the top right to
> display accounts. Go to Settings, then Advanced and hit Reset Account.